# Pasar una variable de un formulario a otro formulario PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo un formulario que es muy grande y por esa razón lo he partido en dos pedazos el primer formulario me registra bien e igual que el segundo el único problema es que cuando hago el registro del segundo formulario no me guarda la cédula del primer formulario esa variable tengo que recibirla tipo hidden ya que tengo dos tablas para guardar esos registros la primera es «`historia_clinica`» que guarda la cedula del paciente y la segunda tabla es «`antecedentes_personales`» que guarda la «`fk_cedula`» que hace referencia a la cedula de la tabla historia clínica.

A continuación anexo los códigos de registro del primer formulario: `registrar_historiaclinica`

```
<!-- formulario de registro-->


<div class="row">

<br>

<form class="" action="registrar_historiaclinica.php" name="frmContacto" method="POST">


<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="cedula" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, no pueden haber espacios en blanco, La C&eacute;dula debe Contener 7 d&iacute;gitos como 
m&iacute;nimo, solo se aceptan n&uacute;meros!" pattern="[0-9]{7,8}" required/>
<label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Cédula:</label>
</div>


<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="nombres" autocomplete="off" title="Se Necesita sus Nombres, Este Campo solo Acepta Letras!" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/>
<label for="nombres" class="black-text ">Nombres:</label>
</div>


<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="apellidos" autocomplete="off" title="Se Necesita sus Nombres, Este Campo solo Acepta Letras!" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/>
<label for="apellidos" class="black-text ">Apellidos:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="number" name="edad" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, La Edad debe Contener 1 d&iacute;gitos como 
m&iacute;nimo, solo se aceptan n&uacute;meros!" pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" required/>
<label for="edad" class="black-text ">Edad:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
 <select class="icons" name="sexo" id="sexo" title="Disculpa, debe seleccionar alguna opción" required/>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una Opción</option>
      <option value="Masculino" data-icon="../img sexo/masculino.jpg" class="circle">Masculino</option>
      <option value="Femenino" data-icon="../img sexo/femenino.jpg" class="circle">Femenino</option>
    </select>
    <label for="sexo" class="black-text ">Sexo</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="date" class="datepicker" name="fecha_nacimiento" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, se necesita la fecha" required/>
<label for="Fecha de Nacimiento" class="black-text ">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="lugar_nacimiento" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, se necesita el lugar de nacimiento" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/>
<label for="Lugar de Nacimiento" class="black-text ">Lugar de Nacimiento:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="religion" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, se necesita la religión!" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/>
<label for="religion" class="black-text ">Religión:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m12">
<textarea  id="direccion" name="direccion" class="materialize-textarea" title="Disculpa, se necesita la Dirección" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
<label for="direccion" class="black-text ">Dirección:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}" autofocus="autofocus" required/>
<label for="email" class="black-text ">E-Mail:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="telefono_habitacion" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, se necesita su numero telefonico de habitacion!" pattern="[0-9]{11,11}" required/>
<label for="telefono de habitacion" class="black-text ">Teléfono de Habitación:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="telefono_celular" autocomplete="off"  title="Disculpa, se necesita su numero telefonico Personal!" pattern="[0-9]{11,11}" required/>
<label for="telefno celular" class="black-text ">Teléfono Celular:</label>
</div>



<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="familiar" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, se necesita un familiar!" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/>
<label for="familiar" class="black-text ">Familiar:</label>
</div>


<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="telefono_familiar" autocomplete="off"  title="Disculpa, se necesita su numero telefonico Familar!" pattern="[0-9]{11,11}" required/>
<label for="telefno familiar" class="black-text ">Teléfono:</label>
</div>




<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="otro" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, debe ingresar alguna informacion!" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/>
<label for="otro" class="black-text ">Otro:</label>
</div>


<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
<select name="fk_seguro" id="fk_seguro" 
title="Disculpa, debe seleccionar alguna opcción!" required/>
<option value=""  disabled selected>Seguro:</option>
<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM seguro ORDER BY id");
while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $linea['tiposeguro'] ;?>">
<?php echo $linea['tiposeguro'] ;?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>



<div class="center-align">

<button class="btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium" type="submit" name="guardar" >
Guardar y Continuar
</button>

<button class="btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium"  type="reset" >
Cancelar
</button>


<a href='historiaclinica.php' 
button class='btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium'type='submit'>
Volver Atrás
</button></a>

</div>



<input type='hidden' name='fecha_creacion_historia_clinica' value='<?php echo date("d/m/Y");?>'>
</form>





</div>

<!-- fin formulario de registro-->




<!-- proceso para registrar-->


<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
$cedula_check = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT cedula FROM historia_clinica  WHERE cedula = :cedula LIMIT 1');
$cedula_check->bindParam(':cedula', $_POST['cedula']);
$cedula_check->execute();
if($cedula_check->rowCount() > 0){
$cedula_check->closeCursor();

echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado ! 
</h5>
</div>";

header("refresh:5;registrar.php");

}else{

$sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO historia_clinica(
id,cedula,nombres,apellidos,edad,sexo,fecha_nacimiento,
lugar_nacimiento,direccion,email,telefono_habitacion,
telefono_celular,familiar,telefono_familiar,otro,
fk_seguro,fecha_creacion_historia_clinica) 

VALUES 

(:id, :cedula, :nombres, :apellidos, :edad, :sexo, :fecha_nacimiento, 
:lugar_nacimiento, :direccion, :email, :telefono_habitacion, :telefono_celular, 
:familiar, :telefono_familiar, :otro, :fk_seguro, :fecha_creacion_historia_clinica)");
$sql->bindParam(':id',$_POST['id']);
$sql->bindParam(':cedula',$_POST['cedula']);
$sql->bindParam(':nombres',$_POST['nombres']);
$sql->bindParam(':apellidos',$_POST['apellidos']);
$sql->bindParam(':edad',$_POST['edad']);
$sql->bindParam(':sexo',$_POST['sexo']);
$sql->bindParam(':fecha_nacimiento',$_POST['fecha_nacimiento']);
$sql->bindParam(':lugar_nacimiento',$_POST['lugar_nacimiento']);
$sql->bindParam(':direccion',$_POST['direccion']);
$sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
$sql->bindParam(':telefono_habitacion',$_POST['telefono_habitacion']);
$sql->bindParam(':telefono_celular',$_POST['telefono_celular']);
$sql->bindParam(':familiar',$_POST['familiar']);
$sql->bindParam(':telefono_familiar',$_POST['telefono_familiar']);
$sql->bindParam(':otro',$_POST['otro']);
$sql->bindParam(':fk_seguro',$_POST['fk_seguro']);
$sql->bindParam(':fecha_creacion_historia_clinica',$_POST['fecha_creacion_historia_clinica']);
$sql->execute();
        }
if($sql)
{
echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;registrar_historiaclinica_antecedentes_personales.php");
}
}
?>

<!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

A continuación anexo los códigos de registro del segundo formulario: `registrar_historiaclinica_antecedentes_personales`

```
    <!-- formulario de registro-->
        <div class="row">
        <br>

        <form class="" action="registrar_historiaclinica_antecedentes_personales.php" name="frmContacto" method="POST">



        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>Motivo de Consulta:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="motivo_consulta" name="motivo_consulta" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>



        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>Enfermedad Actual:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="enfermedad_actual" name="enfermedad_actual" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>


        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>HTA:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="hta" name="hta" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>


        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>DIABETES:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="diabetes" name="diabetes" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>ALERGIA A FARMACOS:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="alergias_farmacos" name="alergias_farmacos" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>QUIRURGICOS:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="quirurgicos" name="quirurgicos" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>OTROS:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="otros" name="otros" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>ANTECEDENTES FAMILIARES:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="antecedentes_familiares" name="antecedentes_familiares" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <h6 class="left-align white-text thin"><b>PSICOBIOLOGICOS:</b></h6>
        <textarea  id="psicobiologicos" name="psicobiologicos" class="materialize-textarea" title="Describe tu Mensaje" autocomplete="off" required/></textarea>
        </div>


        <div class="center-align">
        <button class="btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium" type="submit" name="guardar">
        Crear Historia Clinica
        </button>


        <button class="btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium"  type="reset" >
        Cancelar
        </button>


        <a href='historiaclinica.php' 
        button class='btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium' type='submit'>
        Volver Atrás
        </button></a>

        </div>

        <input type='hidden' name='fk_cedula' value='<?php echo $cedula;?>' id='cedula'>

        </form>


        <!-- proceso para registrar-->


        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
        $cedula_check = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT fk_cedula FROM antecedentes_personales  WHERE fk_cedula = :fk_cedula LIMIT 1');
        $cedula_check->bindParam(':fk_cedula', $_POST['fk_cedula']);
        $cedula_check->execute();
        if($cedula_check->rowCount() > 0){
        $cedula_check->closeCursor();

        echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
        <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
        ¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado ! 
        </h5>
        </div>";

        header("refresh:5;consultar_historiaclinica.php");

        }else{

        $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO antecedentes_personales(
        fk_cedula,motivo_consulta,enfermedad_actual,hta,diabetes,alergias_farmacos,
        quirurgicos,otros,antecedentes_familiares,psicobiologicos) 

        VALUES 

        (:fk_cedula, :motivo_consulta, :enfermedad_actual, :hta, :diabetes, :alergias_farmacos,
        :quirurgicos, :otros, :antecedentes_familiares, :psicobiologicos)");
        $sql->bindParam(':fk_cedula',$_POST['fk_cedula']);
        $sql->bindParam(':motivo_consulta',$_POST['motivo_consulta']);
        $sql->bindParam(':enfermedad_actual',$_POST['enfermedad_actual']);
        $sql->bindParam(':hta',$_POST['hta']);
        $sql->bindParam(':diabetes',$_POST['diabetes']);
        $sql->bindParam(':alergias_farmacos',$_POST['alergias_farmacos']);
        $sql->bindParam(':quirurgicos',$_POST['quirurgicos']);
        $sql->bindParam(':otros',$_POST['otros']);
        $sql->bindParam(':antecedentes_familiares',$_POST['antecedentes_familiares']);
        $sql->bindParam(':psicobiologicos',$_POST['psicobiologicos']);
        $sql->execute();
            }
        if($sql)
        {
        echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
        <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
        ¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !
        </h5>
        </div>";
        header("refresh:5;consultar_historiaclinica.php");
        }
        }
        ?>

        <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->


        </div>
        <!-- fin formulario de registro--

>
```

Comment: ¿De donde viene la variable `$cedula`?

Comment: la variable $cedula viene en el primer formumario

Comment: Pon el código, para ver como pasas esa variable al segundo formulario. ¿Llega a cargarse ese `hidden` con tu variable `$cedula`? Si no es así, tu problema estará en el otro formulario

Comment: <form class="" action="registrar_historiaclinica.php" name="frmContacto" method="POST">


<div class="input-field col s12 m3">
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="cedula" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, no pueden haber espacios en blanco, La C&eacute;dula debe Contener 7 d&iacute;gitos como 
m&iacute;nimo, solo se aceptan n&uacute;meros!" pattern="[0-9]{7,8}" required/>
<label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Cédula:</label>
</div>

Comment: $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO historia_clinica(
id,cedula,nombres,apellidos,edad,sexo,fecha_nacimiento,
lugar_nacimiento,direccion,email,telefono_habitacion,
telefono_celular,familiar,telefono_familiar,otro,
fk_seguro,fecha_creacion_historia_clinica) 

VALUES 
(:id, :cedula, :nombres, :apellidos, :edad, :sexo, :fecha_nacimiento, 
:lugar_nacimiento, :direccion, :email, :telefono_habitacion, :telefono_celular, 
:familiar, :telefono_familiar, :otro, :fk_seguro, :fecha_creacion_historia_clinica)");
$sql->bindParam(':id',$_POST['id']);
$sql->bindParam(':cedula',$_POST['cedula']);

Comment: Edita tu post de la pregunta, para insertar el código. Si lo añades como comentario, no se entiende.

Comment: ok pero a vece me queda mal editado

Comment: Sigo sin encontrar de donde viene el valor de `$cedula`. No lo tienes inicializado en ningún sitio

Comment: primero hago el registro con los datos principales donde se guarda cédula que es en el primero formulario, luego pasa al siguiente formulario donde termino de completar los datos, en la segunda tabla, pero como ya registre la cédula en el primer formulario necesito registrar esa misma cedula en la segunda tabla porque seria la relación cedula con fk_cedula, osea no se si me entiendes como ya guarde cedula en el primer formulario necesito mantener la variable cedula en el segundo formulario tipo hidden para que me guarde esa misma cedula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues lo que Veo es que te hace falta agregar el Valor de la Cédula al segundo formulario.. Si estuvieras incluyendo el Segundo formulario Harias algo como esto:

```
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
```

Para que el segundo formulario te reconozca la variable simplemente eso.

**PERO** estas haciendo esto:

```
header("refresh:5;registrar_historiaclinica_antecedentes_personales.php");
```

Lo que hace que hagas un Redirect, a la pagina php con el segundo formulario entonces necesitas agregar por Parametro URL el varlor de la cédula:

```
header("refresh:5;registrar_historiaclinica_antecedentes_personales.php?cedula=".$_POST['cedula']);
```

Y en Tu Segundo Formuario Debes hacer esto:

```
<input type='hidden' name='fk_cedula' value='<?php echo $_GET['cedula'];?>' id='cedula'>
```

Asi le pasas por parametro de la url el valor de la cédula, y lo tendrás disponible.